# Hide parent element based on value of child element

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to create a filter function which hides divs based on values of p tags. The behavior should be the following:

**User selects a filter, e.g. >5**:

- Loop through all p-tags with a certain class
- If the value within the p-tag matches the filter (>5), hide all parent divs of each p-tag which value doesn't match the filter value

My solution is the following:

```
function eraseThis() {

counter = 0
tagList = document.getElementsByClassName("rating")

$(".rating").each(function()
{
if (this.innerHTML < 5) {
     $(this).parent().hide() 
}

counter = counter + 1

    });
}
```

This gives me the results I'm looking for but I'm wondering if there's a more elegant / efficient way to do it ?

The markup would be something like:

```
<div class="movie">
 <p class="rating"> some value </p>
</div>

<div class="movie">
 <p class="rating"> some value </p>
</div>
```

and so on

Comment: See [.parent()](https://api.jquery.com/parent/)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour], have a look around, and read through the [help], in particular [*How do I ask a good question?*](/help/how-to-ask) Include an example of your HTML structure in the question, and preferably include a [mcve] demonstrating the problem, ideally a **runnable** one using Stack Snippets (the `[<>]` toolbar button; [here's how to do one](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-do-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do-tha)).

Comment: @AlexYokisama: I suspect you meant [`.parents`](https://api.jquery.com/parents/) (plural).

Comment: @T.J.Crowder, maybe. That depends on markup, that we can't see in this question. For closest parent only `.parent()` will be enough.

Comment: @AlexYokisama@T.J.Crowder

thanks guys, changed the code and added some info regarding the  markup

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this should do the trick :

**JQuery code :**

```
function eraseThis() {
    var tagList = $(".rating");
    tagList.each(function(){

        var $this = $(this);
        if (parseInt( $this.text() ) < 5) {
            $this.parent().hide();
        }

    });
}
```

**Html code :**

```
<div class="movie">
 <p class="rating">2</p>
</div>

<div class="movie">
 <p class="rating">9</p>
</div>
```

And here is the full code : [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/a2ooc3dq/2/)

Comment: nice, great job. Just corrected parents() to parent() .

Comment: @cubebb : Anytime :-D

Comment: @cubebb: I corrected it just after I saw the html code.